# Why is ObservableCollection updating UI on Android but not iOS?[Pendent]

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have a cross-platform app on Xamarin forms for android and iOS.

In some view, i am using an ObservableCollection as Source of a `ListView`.

In the listview there are buttons that users can interact and change the UI.

On android everything is working fine but when i tested it on iOS, the changes are performed only after 1 click.

I used MVVM architecture to accomplish my needs and it works very well on android.. the only problem is iPhone.

c# code :

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ConvidarAmigosEmail : ContentView
    {
        public ConvidarAmigosEmail ()
        {
                        BindingContext = new ConvidarAmigosEmailViewModel();
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void ListaEmail_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
            listaEmail.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class ConvidarAmigosEmailViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<Contacto> _contactosComEmail;
        public ObservableCollection<Contacto> ContactosComEmail { get => _contactosComEmail; set { _contactosComEmail = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ContactosComEmail)); } }

        public ICommand SeleccionarContacto
        {
            get => new Command<Contacto>((contacto) =>
            {
                if (!contacto.Seleccionado)
                {
                    contacto.Seleccionado = !contacto.Seleccionado;
                    contacto.Opcao = AppResource.Seleccionado;
                    ContactosSeleccionadosEmail.Add(contacto);
                }
                else
                {
                    contacto.Seleccionado = !contacto.Seleccionado;
                    contacto.Opcao = AppResource.Select;
                    ContactosSeleccionadosEmail.Remove(contacto);
                }
            });
        }

        public ICommand SeleccionarTodos
        {
            get => new Command(() =>
            {
                if (ContactosComEmail.Count != ContactosSeleccionadosEmail.Count)
                {
                    ContactosSeleccionadosEmail.Clear();
                    foreach (var obj in ContactosComEmail)
                    {
                        obj.Seleccionado = true;
                        obj.Opcao = AppResource.Seleccionado;
                        ContactosSeleccionadosEmail.Add(obj);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ContactosSeleccionadosEmail.Clear();
                    foreach (var obj in ContactosComEmail)
                    {
                        obj.Seleccionado = false;
                        obj.Opcao = AppResource.Select;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public List<Contacto> ContactosSeleccionadosEmail { get; set; } = new List<Contacto>();

        private string _textoSelectTodos = AppResource.SelTodos;
        public string TextoSelectTodos
        {
            get
            {

                if (ContactosSeleccionadosEmail.Count == ContactosComEmail.Count)
                {
                    _textoSelectTodos = AppResource.Anull;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextoSelectTodos));
                    return _textoSelectTodos;
                }
                _textoSelectTodos = AppResource.SelTodos;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextoSelectTodos));
                return _textoSelectTodos;
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public ConvidarAmigosEmailViewModel()
        {
            ContactosComEmail = new ObservableCollection<Contacto>();
            ObterContactos();
        }

        #region ObterContactos
        /*
         Params Entrada => nenhum
         Params Saída   => nenhum
         Lógica         => Passo 1 : Acede a lista de contactos do telefone e extrai os dados;
                           Passo 2 : Coloca os contactos com email na variável ContactosE; os que não têm email em ContactosT
                           Passo 3 : ContentLoader para aceder ao caminho real do ficheiro de imagem (foto) do contacto;
                           Passo 4 : Adiciona os contactos com Email a uma lista da classe "Contacto", Contactos#. Os sem email para ContactosT
         Plugins : Obter permissoes => https://www.nuget.org/packages/plugin.permissions/;
                   Aceder aos contactos =>
        */
        public async void ObterContactos()
        {
            //verifica se aplicacao tem permissao pra aceder a lista de contactos
            var statusPermissao = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Contacts);

            //requisitar permissao 
            if (statusPermissao == PermissionStatus.Unknown)
            {
                var resposta = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Contacts);
                statusPermissao = resposta[Permission.Contacts];
            }

            if (statusPermissao == PermissionStatus.Denied)
            {
                var op = await App.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert(AppResource.contactosNegados, AppResource.SemFuncionalidade, AppResource.Definicoes, AppResource.MaisTarde);

                if (op == true)
                {
                    CrossPermissions.Current.OpenAppSettings();
                }

                else
                {
                    await App.Current?.MainPage?.Navigation?.PopAsync();
                }
            }

            if (statusPermissao == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var contactos = await Plugin.ContactService.CrossContactService.Current.GetContactListAsync();
                //contactos com email
                var contactosE = contactos.Where(x => x.Email != null).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

                //imagem inicial de cada contacto, caso esta não tenha imagem de perfil.
                var aux = ImageSource.FromResource("KiaiDay.Images.user.png");
                foreach (var c in contactosE)
                {
                    aux = ImageSource.FromResource("KiaiDay.Images.user.png");
                    if (c.PhotoUri != null)
                    {
                        //caso tenho imagem de perfil, aceder ao caminho real no ficheiro e extrair a imagem
                        var contentLoader = DependencyService.Get<IContentLoader>();
                        var uri = new Uri(c.PhotoUri);
                        aux = contentLoader.LoadFromContentUri(uri);
                    }

                    ContactosComEmail.Add(
                        new Contacto()
                        {
                            Email = c.Email,
                            Foto = aux,
                            Numero = c.Number,
                            Nome = c.Name,
                            Opcao = AppResource.Select
                        });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //await App.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert(AppResource.contactosNegados, AppResource.SemFuncionalidade, AppResource.ok);
                //App.Current?.MainPage?.Navigation?.PopAsync();
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

xaml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="KiaiDay.Views.PosLogin.ConvidarAmigosEmail" x:Name="pagina"
             xmlns:FFIL="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
             xmlns:FFT="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Padding="8" BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2" Margin="-25,0,0,0"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" BorderColor="LightGray" HasShadow="False">
                    <Frame.CornerRadius>
                        <OnPlatform Android="80" iOS="10"/>
                    </Frame.CornerRadius>
                    <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding TextoSelectTodos}" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFont}" TextColor="{Binding CorSelectTodos}" FontSize="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding SeleccionarTodos}"/>
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>


            <ListView SeparatorColor="LightGray" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactosComEmail}" HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="listaEmail"
                      Margin="30,0,30,0" ItemSelected="ListaEmail_ItemSelected" IsGroupingEnabled="False" Grid.Row="1" CachingStrategy="RetainElement">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid ColumnSpacing="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <FFIL:CachedImage Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Source="{Binding Foto}" DownsampleToViewSize="True" BitmapOptimizations="False"
                                    Aspect="AspectFit" RetryCount="0" RetryDelay="250" HeightRequest="50" 
                                    LoadingPriority="Highest" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                    FadeAnimationForCachedImages="False" WidthRequest="50">
                                    <FFIL:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                        <FFT:CircleTransformation/>
                                    </FFIL:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                </FFIL:CachedImage>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Nome}" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFont}" TextColor="#3c3c3b" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Email}" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFont}" TextColor="#3c3c3b" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                                <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Padding="8" BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" BorderColor="LightGray" HasShadow="False">
                                    <Frame.CornerRadius>
                                        <OnPlatform Android="80" iOS="10"/>
                                    </Frame.CornerRadius>
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <FFIL:CachedImage Source="{Binding Icone}" HeightRequest="8" WidthRequest="8" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" 
                                            VerticalOptions="Center" LoadingPriority="Highest" RetryCount="0" RetryDelay="250" DownsampleToViewSize="True" BitmapOptimizations="False"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Opcao}" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFont}" FontSize="8" TextColor="{Binding Cor}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>


                                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference pagina},Path=BindingContext.SeleccionarContacto}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Frame>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

I expect the ObservableCollection to update the UI on iOS without needing to click.

EDIT : 
Used plugins => https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin;
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ContactsPlugin;

model definition

```
 public class Contacto : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEntity
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Numero { get; set; }


        [Ignore]
        public ImageSource Foto { get; set; }

        private ImageSource _icone = ImageSource.FromFile("mais.png");
        [Ignore] public ImageSource Icone
        {
            get
            {
                if (Seleccionado)
                {
                    _icone = ImageSource.FromFile("certo.png");
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Icone));
                    return _icone;
                }
                _icone = ImageSource.FromFile("mais.png");
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Icone));
                return _icone;
            }
            set
            {
                _icone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Icone));
            }
        }

        private string _opcao;
        [Ignore]
        public string Opcao
        {
            get
            {
                return _opcao;
            }
            set
            {
                _opcao = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Opcao));
            }
        }


        private bool _seleccionado = false;
        public bool Seleccionado
        {
            get
            {
                return _seleccionado;
            }
            set
            {
                _seleccionado = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Seleccionado));
            }
        }


        private Color _cor = Color.FromHex("#3c3c3b");
        [Ignore]
        public Color Cor
        {
            get
            {
                if (Seleccionado)
                {
                    _cor = Color.FromHex("#4297d3");
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Cor));
                    return _cor;
                }
                _cor = Color.FromHex("#3c3c3b");
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Cor));
                return _cor;
            }
            set
            {
                _cor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Cor));
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

EDIT2: After changing constructor of the view model, the view was getting updated but i couldnt do anything else. It looked like it was blocked.

```
        public ConvidarAmigosEmailViewModel()
        {
            ContactosComEmail = new ObservableCollection<Contacto>();
            Task.Run(async () => { await ObterContactos(); });
        }
```

EDIT3: After spending a lot of time trying to figure out what was happening, i came to conclusion that the problem was with this part of code:

```
                                <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Padding="8" BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" HasShadow="False">
                                    <Frame.CornerRadius>
                                        <OnPlatform Android="80" iOS="10"/>
                                    </Frame.CornerRadius>
                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <FFIL:CachedImage Source="{Binding Icone}" HeightRequest="8" WidthRequest="8" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" 
                                            DownsampleToViewSize="True" BitmapOptimizations="False" Aspect="AspectFit" RetryCount="0" RetryDelay="250"
                                            LoadingPriority="Highest" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FadeAnimationForCachedImages="False"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Opcao}" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFont}" FontSize="8" TextColor="{Binding Cor}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>


                                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference pagina},Path=BindingContext.SeleccionarContacto}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Frame>
```

I dont know why this is happening...

Comment: Maybe moving BindingContext after InitializeComponent. This always a good practice to ensure all components are created. But I'm not sure if I'm undestanding your question.

Comment: Hi @Uraitz after using await key on constructor. the view got updated but it seemed that thread was blocked. i couldnt do anything else.
I changed this on constructor `Task.Run(async ()=> { await ObterContactos(); });`

Comment: I think that you should load this data on page's OnAppearing, after ViewModel constructor. With this you will solve OnResume problems when your app goes to background. Almost, you are using DisplayAlert inside this new thread this calls will need Device.BeginMainThreadInvoke if you don't want to crash you r app.

Comment: but how to do that on viewmodel ?

Comment: Create a function like ViewModel.Initialize() and call from OnAppearing

Comment: @Uraitz could u watch my Edit ? The problem is on xaml file.. idk why...

Comment: @user11712761 Hi , you mean that not work in IOS, have you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be enough, its dificult without debugger and source code.

ConvidarAmigosEmail.xaml

```
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class ConvidarAmigosEmail : ContentView
        {
            public ConvidarAmigosEmailViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
            public ConvidarAmigosEmail ()
            {
                ViewModel = new ConvidarAmigosEmailViewModel();
                InitializeComponent ();
                BindingContext = new ConvidarAmigosEmailViewModel();
            }

            public async override OnAppearing()
            {
                // will be good that you show loading icon while processing data
                await ViewModel.LoadData();
            }
            private void ListaEmail_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
                listaEmail.SelectedItem = null;
            }

            private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Viewmodel creation

```
    public ConvidarAmigosEmailViewModel()
        {
            ContactosComEmail = new ObservableCollection<Contacto>();

        }

        public async Task LoadData()
        {
            await ObterContactos();
        }
```

Inside ObterContactos

```
      //imagem inicial de cada contacto, caso esta não tenha imagem de perfil.
            var aux = ImageSource.FromResource("KiaiDay.Images.user.png");
            var ListContactos = new List<Contacto>();
            foreach (var c in contactosE)
            {
                aux = ImageSource.FromResource("KiaiDay.Images.user.png");
                if (c.PhotoUri != null)
                {
                    //caso tenho imagem de perfil, aceder ao caminho real no ficheiro e extrair a imagem
                    var contentLoader = DependencyService.Get<IContentLoader>();
                    var uri = new Uri(c.PhotoUri);
                    aux = contentLoader.LoadFromContentUri(uri);
                }

                // Add method inside foreach generate too many innecesary property changed
                // notifications
                ListContactos.Add(
                    new Contacto()
                    {
                        Email = c.Email,
                        Foto = aux,
                        Numero = c.Number,
                        Nome = c.Name,
                        Opcao = AppResource.Select
                    });
            }

            ObterContactos = new ObservableCollection<Contacto>(ListContactos);
        }
        else
...
```

Comment: `ContentView` has no `OnApearing` to override.

Comment: But like i said, error is on xaml file. When i remove edit 3, it works well.

Comment: Sorry about content view, you can call from ContentView's OnAppearing. ConvidarAmigosEmail.ViewModel.LoadData(). I would try to remove OnPropertyChanged from Get methods, i'm not sure but when property changed this property's get method is called. xaml code look normal.

Comment: Should i add a sample for u to look at ?

Comment: thanks Uraitz. I dont know how honestly ... but after i closed and reopened the solution, everything was working fine. Thanks a lot for the help and the patience. I will mark your answer as correct.